# How to convert Stata marksample in R language?

Tags: r, stata

I am new to Stata, but I need to think about converting  a piece of Stata code to R for later convenience.

One piece of Stata code is following

```
marksample touse
quietly: keep if `touse'
```

From help(marksample) in Stata, I think marksample is going to give Index to each row of the data sets and mark each row as 1 when it is qualified, or 0 otherwise. There are several rules applied.

*1.  The marker variable is set to 0 in observations for which weight is 0 (but see option zeroweight).
2.  The appropriate error message is issued, and everything stops if weight is invalid (such as being less than 0 in some observation or being a
        noninteger for frequency weights).
3.  The marker variable is set to 0 in observations for which the if exp is not satisfied.
4.  The marker variable is set to 0 in observations outside the in range.
5.  The marker variable is set to 0 in observations for which any of the numeric variables in varlist contain a numeric missing value.
6.  The marker variable is set to 0 in all observations if any of the variables in varlist are strings; see option strok for an exception.
7.  The marker variable is set to 1 in the remaining observations.
Using the name touse is a convention, not a rule, but it is recommended for consistency between programs.*

May I know if there is anyway in R to convert this part of code easily (packages or functions)? Or I have to create the rules in R manually by myself?

Answer (score 2):

The closest one might be

```
foo <- function(df, condition) {
    touse <- with(df, eval(parse(text = condition)))
    subset(df, touse)
}
foo(df, "bar < 0")
```

But if you don't care about `touse' then you can do

```
foo <- function(df, condition) {
    subset(df, eval(parse(text = condition)))
}
foo(df, "bar < 0")
```

And if you don't need a function wrapper you can actually do

```
subset(df, bar < 0)
```

directly.

**EDIT**

Stata's `marksample` by default parses Stata syntax; typically if you have a program defined as

```
program foo
    syntax [varlist] [if] [in] [fw aw pw iw]
    marksample touse
    quietly: keep if `touse'
end
```

The program above will parse the syntax call. `if` has an obvious equivalent. For the rest:

1. `marksample` also sets `touse` to 0 outside the in range. An equivalent call is `1:nrow(df) %in% start:end`
2. `marksample` also sets `touse` to 0 if any rows have missing values. An equivalent in R would be `complete.cases(df)`
3. `marksample` also sets `touse` to 0 if any columns are string. An equivalent in R would be `apply(df, 1, is.character)`
4. For weights, I don't think R has a universal convention the way Stata does. Several R functions can do weights, but without more context I am not sure how to code it.

combining 1-3, a closer equivalent to the Stata syntas parsing is

```
foo <- function(df,
                varlist = colnames(df),
                if_condition = "TRUE",
                in_range = 1:nrow(df)) {
    touse <- with(df[, varlist, drop = FALSE], eval(parse(text = if_condition))) &
             1:nrow(df) %in% in_range &
             complete.cases(df[, varlist, drop = FALSE]) &
             !apply(df[, varlist, drop = FALSE], 1, is.character)
    subset(df, touse)
}
foo(df, varlist = c("var1", "var2"), if_condition = "var1 < 0", in_range = 2:8)
```

Comment: Do you mean `bar` is the name of the variables? Should I consider all of the variables of the data table or just the columns that I am interested in?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2a. It would be more efficient to just use the columns you want; by default, however, all columns are kept, just like in Stata. 2b. However, my answer does not mimic everything `marksample` does; I think based on the original question I interpreted it as parsing "if" only. As pointed out, `marksample` also parses varlist and weights, which do not have an obvious equivalent in R unless you are also coding them.

Comment: thank you! if I could have the weight variables, do you mean that I could get more close results to `marksample`?

Comment: I don't think R has a generic way of doing weights in the way Stata does. If you need to use weights as well, then you would need to post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are trying to do and we can go from there.